# How can I print only the lines for a file that contain consecutive digits?

Tags: programming

I have a text file containing a list of numbers. I want to print only the lines that contain a number, the digits of which are consecutive digits.

The input list:

123
321
567
765
124
568

The output should be:

123
321
567
765

Comment: `Pick` and `Cases` could do the job?

Answer (score 1):

```
consecutive = Total[Abs[Differences[IntegerDigits@FromDigits@#]] - 1] &;
string = "123 321 567 765 124 568";
Pick[#,  consecutive /@ #, 0]& @ StringSplit[string]
```

> {"123", "321", "567", "765"}

Comment: Thank you @AccidentalFourierTransform.